# Leading behavior of ODE near Irregular singular point

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I have hard time trying to find the leading behavior of the following ODE as $x\rightarrow \infty$:
$$ x^{7} y'' = e^{x} y$$
I've tried to use the substitution:
$$ y = e^{S(x)}$$
and using the method of dominant balance I assumed:
$$ (S')^{2} \gg S''$$
As a result:
$$ (S')^{2}  \sim \frac{e^{x}}{x^{7}}$$
Usually I would try to integrate but it seems like I'm missing something.

I saw a similar question in Advanced Mathematical Methods by Bender in page 140 but he didn't mention how to deal with it.

Comment: Try with $y(x)=\sum_{i\geq 0}a_i x^{i+r}$

Comment: If I understands correctly you propose some kind of Frobenius series, but is it the proper way to solve it for Irregular singular points? I think you get diverging series if you plug it back in?

Answer (score 1):

So I answered my question:
We are looking at the limit $x\rightarrow 0$ and therefore
$$\frac{e^{x}}{x^7} \sim \frac{1}{x^7}, \text{ as } x\rightarrow 0$$
and from here it is solvable.